# Dynamic LWC Datatable using template for:each to populate column headers/row data

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, lightning-datatable

I am trying to use  to dynamically fill column headers and row data in a data table. I am able to dynamically create the column headers with the template for:each but when it comes to using template for:each to dynamically create the row data all the data sticks to one column instead of being assigned to the correct column. The timeslot.slot is embedded inside the appointment item so I need context of the appointment item when I am looping in my table row creation. This is what I have so far.

```
<template>
    <lightning-card class="slds-card_boundary">
        <div class="slds-card__body slds-card__body_inner">
            <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_cell-buffer slds-var-m-bottom_large">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="slds-text-title_caps">
                        <template if:true={appointments}>
                            <template for:each={appointments} for:item="appointment">
                                <th key={appointment.date}>
                                    <div class="slds-truncate">{appointment.newDateLabel}</div>
                                </th>
                            </template>
                        </template>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <template if:true={appointments}>
                        <template for:each={appointments} for:item="appointment">
                            <template for:each={appointment.timeslots} for:item="timeslot">
                                <tr key={timeslot.Id}>
                                    <td>
                                        <template if:true={timeslot.selected}>
                                            <button data-id={timeslot.id} class="vlocity-btn slds-button slds-button_brand slds-size_1-of-1 slds-p-horizontal_none slds-text-align_center selected-timeslot" type="button" onclick={selectAppointment}>{timeslot.slot}</button>
                                        </template>
                                        <template if:false={timeslot.selected}>
                                            <button data-id={timeslot.id} class="vlocity-btn slds-button slds-button_outline-brand slds-size_1-of-1 slds-p-horizontal_none slds-text-align_center" type="button" onclick={selectAppointment}>{timeslot.slot}</button>
                                        </template>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </template>
                        </template>
                    </template>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

[image: This is how my table looks with the above html]

[image: This is how my data from my mock api is strucured]

Is this kinda thing possible in a datatable? One for loop inside of another?

Comment: If you'd be so kind to [edit] your question to include your data as JSON or something, I'd be happy to write something up for you.

Answer (score 1):

In summary, your code won't work because you don't have the necessary data structure. You need a multidimensional array of values that represent your data. That matrix would look something like this:

```
[
  {
    "Id": 0,
    "timeslots": [
      {
        "slot": "3:00pm - 4:00pm",
        "id": 0
      },
      {
        "slot": "9:00am - 11:00am",
        "id": 1
      },
      {
        "slot": "8:00am - 9:00am",
        "id": 2
      },
      {
        "slot": "7:00am - 8:00am",
        "id": 3
      },
      {
        "slot": "9:00am - 11:00am",
        "id": 4
      },
      {
        "slot": "1:00pm - 2:00pm",
        "id": 5
      },
      {
        "slot": "1:00pm - 2:00pm",
        "id": 6
      },
      {
        "slot": "1:00pm - 2:00pm",
        "id": 7
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 1,
    "timeslots": [
      {
        "id": 0
      },
      {
        "slot": "1:00pm - 2:00pm",
        "id": 1
      },
      {
        "slot": "3:00pm - 4:00pm",
        "id": 2
      },
      {
        "slot": "10:00am - 11:00am",
        "id": 3
      },
      {
        "id": 4
      },
      {
        "id": 5
      },
      {
        "id": 6
      },
      {
        "id": 7
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 2,
    "timeslots": [
      {
        "id": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 1
      },
      {
        "slot": "4:00pm - 5:00pm",
        "id": 2
      },
      {
        "slot": "2:00pm - 3:00pm",
        "id": 3
      },
      {
        "id": 4
      },
      {
        "id": 5
      },
      {
        "id": 6
      },
      {
        "id": 7
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id": 3,
    "timeslots": [
      {
        "id": 0
      },
      {
        "id": 1
      },
      {
        "id": 2
      },
      {
        "slot": "3:00pm - 4:00pm",
        "id": 3
      },
      {
        "id": 4
      },
      {
        "id": 5
      },
      {
        "id": 6
      },
      {
        "id": 7
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Which I derived by using the following code:

```
  get appointmentHeaders() {
    let headers = DATES.reduce((p,v) => {
      p.add(v.Date);
      return p;
    }, new Set());
    let results = Array.from(headers);
    results.sort();
    return results;
  }
  get appointments() {
    let headers = this.appointmentHeaders;
    console.log(headers);
    let columns = Object.fromEntries(headers.map(entry => ([entry, []])));
    DATES.forEach(date => columns[date.Date].push(date.Slot));
    let maxCount = Object.values(columns).reduce((p,v) => (p < v.length? v.length: p), 0);
    let rows = [...new Array(maxCount).keys()]
      .map((Id) => ({ 
        Id, timeslots: 
        headers.map((date, id) => 
          ({slot: columns[date][Id], id})
        )
      }));
    return rows;
  }
```

Where we basically just gather all the dates into a first array, then assign each slot into date buckets, then iterate over the rows for each bucket, ultimately resulting in the nested array demonstrated above.

It's also worth noting your template is incorrect; you need one `tr` per row. That looks like:

```
                    <template for:each={appointments} for:item="appointment">
                        <tr key={appointment.Id}>
                            <template for:each={appointment.timeslots} for:item="timeslot">
                                <td key={timeslot.id}>
                                    <template if:true={timeslot.selected}>
                                        <button data-id={timeslot.id} class="vlocity-btn slds-button slds-button_brand slds-size_1-of-1 slds-p-horizontal_none slds-text-align_center selected-timeslot" type="button" onclick={selectAppointment}>{timeslot.slot}</button>
                                    </template>
                                    <template if:false={timeslot.selected}>
                                        <button data-id={timeslot.id} class="vlocity-btn slds-button slds-button_outline-brand slds-size_1-of-1 slds-p-horizontal_none slds-text-align_center" type="button" onclick={selectAppointment}>{timeslot.slot}</button>
                                    </template>
                                </td>
                            </template>
                        </tr>
                    </template>
```

I've included the entire thing as a [webcomponent.dev](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/SG36BRTE009bhlV8wbm8/src/app.html?p=stories) demo.

Additional work would be necessary to organize the slots such that they align up correctly time-wise. I leave this as an exercise to the reader (hint, you'll need to make your data more accessible via a start time and end time property to line up the rows).